# popup dismiss android

Tags: android, popup

I am implementing a popup in android. I can dismiss it when I click outside of the popup, but I want to dismiss it when I click on same imageview/button as well.

```
1.on click on button1 it opens pop up
2.If I click outside it closes pop up
3.If I click on button1(when pop up is open), it closes pop and reopens it again
```

what I want is
If I click on button1(when pop up is open), it just closes pop and donot reopen unless second click.

Is this possible?

NOTE: I donot want to have a close button inside popup window.

```
 pop_one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                 public void onClick(final View v) {

                    pop_one.getLocationOnScreen(location);

                         p = new Point();

                         p.x = location[0];

                         p.y = location[1];

                     popupshow(one_one_text,pop_one);


                 }
             });
```

And the method is:

```
public void popupshow(String pop_text, ImageView pop_one) {


    int width = display.getWidth(); // deprecated
    System.out.println("jsfjsfjnsdf"+width);
    int new_width = width-(width/6) ;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
            .getBaseContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.career_options_popup_short, null);

    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, new_width,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    TextView popup_text = (TextView) popupView
            .findViewById(R.id.popup_text);
    popup_text.setMinimumWidth(300);
    popup_text.setText(pop_text);
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(popupView,p.x/10, p.y +p.x/8);

    System.out.println("value of x" + p.x+" "+p.y);

    //System.out.println("value of new width " + new_width+"  get width  "+popupWindow.getWidth()+" text box width "+popup_text.getWidth()+"pop view"+popupView.getWidth());
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);



}
```

Regards,
Asmi

Answer (score -1, accepted):

what you need is a `boolean` isShowing set this `boolean` to be true in the function `popupshow`

like this

```
public void popupshow(String pop_text, ImageView pop_one) {

    isShowing=true;
    int width = display.getWidth(); // deprecated
    System.out.println("jsfjsfjnsdf"+width);
    int new_width = width-(width/6) ;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
            .getBaseContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.career_options_popup_short, null);

    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, new_width,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    TextView popup_text = (TextView) popupView
            .findViewById(R.id.popup_text);
    popup_text.setMinimumWidth(300);
    popup_text.setText(pop_text);
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(popupView,p.x/10, p.y +p.x/8);

    System.out.println("value of x" + p.x+" "+p.y);

    //System.out.println("value of new width " + new_width+"  get width  "+popupWindow.getWidth()+" text box width "+popup_text.getWidth()+"pop view"+popupView.getWidth());
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);



}
```

now when you click on `button1` just check for this `boolean`

```
pop_one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                 public void onClick(final View v) {

                  if(isShowing)
                  {
                       popupWindow.dismiss();
                       isShowing=false;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    pop_one.getLocationOnScreen(location);

                     p = new Point();

                     p.x = location[0];

                     p.y = location[1];

                     popupshow(one_one_text,pop_one);

}
                 }
             });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will solve your problem call this on button click

```
popupWindow.dismiss();
```

Comment: Where should I put this popupWindow.dismiss();, I donot want to have a close button inside popup

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the property `setOutsideTouchable(false)` of popup window